# Dataframe won't save as anything - table, global temp view or temp view

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

A dataframe won't save as a table , be it permanent or temp - no error message is given.

I have tried :

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp_table")

# or

df.createGlobalTempView("tmp_table")

# or

df.writeTo("tmp_table")
```

I try to check the table using:

```
spark.sql("SHOW TABLES like 'tmp_table'")

# or

spark.sql("SHOW TABLES like 'global_temp.tmp_table'") # for global view
```

Nothing is displayed, there is not such view or table.

PySpark Version :3.1.2

Any ideas what could be at fault here?

Later Edit: this problem is happening when using spark streaming - it is not replicated in batch

Later Later Edit: Based on some logic change in the script, and because I need to process the json data, if I run this ( first time i use spark context in the script )

```
df_schema = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda x: x.data)).schema
```

the createOrReplaceTempView doesn't work.

If I don't try to do the schema logic and just run this first time with spark context

```
df = spark.read.json(another_df.rdd.map(lambda x: x.body))
```

The views are created properly.
Could it be a spark context thing?
Thanks

Comment: after doing df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp_table"), are you sure you have not killed the kernel/clear state etc.? It should work. Have you also tried to do "SELECT * FROM tmp_table".

Comment: 100% sure - the select query ends in error as no table or view named "tmp_table" is found

Comment: then, make sure that you are referring to the same Spark context.

Comment: i don;t understand why this should be happening inside the same notebook.
I will add the following fact to the problem - this is happening in spark streaming - in batch, the error is not replicated.